# Taylor series of $f(z)=z\sin^2(z)$ at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Everyone,
I'm stuck on the series of $f(z)=z\sin^2(z)$ at $z=i$. I tried by doing

$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{4}(z-i+i)(e^{2i(z-i+i)}-e^{-2i(z-i+i)}).$$

I developed the Taylor Series but I need only the $n$-th coefficient of the series but there I can't find a way to express the series as only

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-i)^n.$$

What's the easiest way to get the Taylor Series of $f(z)$?

Comment: Hint: $$\sin(z)=\sin((z-i)+i)=\sin(z-i)\cosh(1)+i\cos(z-i)\sinh(1)$$